# This error for everything i do

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I get this error also if i ran "Rails s", or "rails generate active_admin:install" or everything else... What it's mean?

i already run "bundle install" or "bundle update". (RAILS 3.1.3)

```
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:198:in `to_proc': undefined method `to_sym' for #<Hash:0x1038c0498> (NoMethodError)
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/devise-1.5.2/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:190:in `map!'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/devise-1.5.2/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:190:in `devise_for'
        from /Users/leonardopellicciotta/dev/webtelevideo/config/routes.rb:7
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:258:in `instance_exec'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:258:in `eval_block'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:235:in `draw'
        from /Users/leonardopellicciotta/dev/webtelevideo/config/routes.rb:1
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:234:in `load'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:234:in `load'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load_dependency'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:640:in `new_constants_in'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load_dependency'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:234:in `load'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:29:in `load_paths'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:29:in `each'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:29:in `load_paths'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:13:in `reload!'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/application.rb:87:in `reload_routes!'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activeadmin-0.3.4/lib/active_admin/reloader.rb:34:in `reload!'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activeadmin-0.3.4/lib/active_admin/reloader.rb:28:in `initialize'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:32:in `call'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:32:in `execute_if_updated'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activeadmin-0.3.4/lib/active_admin/reloader.rb:45:in `_callback_before_19'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:404:in `_run_prepare_callbacks'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `send'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:46:in `prepare!'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:41
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `run_initializers'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/application.rb:96:in `initialize!'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `send'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
        from /Users/leonardopellicciotta/dev/webtelevideo/config/environment.rb:5
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load_dependency'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:640:in `new_constants_in'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load_dependency'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/application.rb:83:in `require_environment!'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:22
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6
```

And if i run this: "rake about"

```
rake aborted!
undefined method `to_sym' for #<Hash:0x1034ddec0>

Tasks: TOP => about => environment
```

Comment: Which version of Ruby are your running?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your `routes.rb`, you've:

```
devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
```

Replace it with:

```
devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
```